# Is Nesting Events a Good Practice in Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a more effecient way of changing the `mouseout` state when a button is clicked?
When a button is clicked I want the image in the click event to take precedence over the image in the mouseout event. 
The following code works but I'm not sure if nesting events is a good practice.

```
$("#targetBtn").on({
   "mouseover" : function() {
      document.querySelector('#targetBtn img').src = 'images/_hover.png';
    },
    "mouseout" : function() {
      document.querySelector('#targetBtn img').src = 'images/_mouseout.png';
    },
    "click" : function() {
      document.querySelector('#targetBtn img').src = 'images/_selected.png';
      $(this).mouseout(function() {
          document.querySelector('#targetBtn img').src = 'images/_selected.png';
      });
    }
});
```

If anyone could refactor this code and show me a better way of doing this it would be greatly appreciated. Also if someone could explain why nesting events is bad (if indeed it is) I would appreciate that as well.

Comment: Well, you'll be resetting it with a brand new function every click, which seems pointless. If you want to *keep* the image once it's been clicked, which I *think* is your intent, why not just remove the mousout handler?

Comment: Not really on topic, but if you only care about this example then you should just use CSS for this kind of behavior.

Comment: And as a side note, it is bad practice to mix plain js method with jQuery ones. Using `document.querySelector` just makes your code harder to read

Comment: Use `$('yourquery')` instead of `document.querySelector('yourquery')`. This question is offtopic on this site (you should post it on codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please clarify the intention of your code. Event nesting is not evil *per se* (nothing is evil per se, contrary to the common misconception), unless used when not appropriate.

Comment: @webDev please post this exact question in codereview.stackexchange.com. It is a good question, but in that site.

Comment: @freedomn-m why is not an option to migrate the question to codereview.SE among the listed options in the close dialog?

Comment: This is not a code review issue. This code won't work as OP intends it to

Comment: @LuisMasuelli because [reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311348/what-is-the-latest-on-adding-code-review-to-off-topic-migration-options)

Comment: @LuisMasuelli `<pedant hat>` because SO users tend to get it wrong, like they have in this case `</pedant hat>`

Comment: @freedomn-m you shouldn't close questions because "they belong on another site" for more information, [please read up on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251568/213556)

Comment: @charlietfl "The following code works" - it does work exactly as OP intends it to, but they want it refactored (ie *code reviewed*) to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - A.Wolff. should I do something like this insted? (bear with me i'm trying to get better with js/JQuery) `$('#targetBtn img').attr('src','images/_mouseout.png');`

Comment: @Vogel612 thanks for the 'reasons' link - very informative.  I would change my close vote reason, but it would still be a close vote.

Comment: @freedomn-m no it won't due to adding conflicting mouseout handlers

Comment: @charlietfl as jquery events trigger in the order they are bound, it's not ideal (hence need for review...) but does as it says.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. You guys have helped me better understand what's going on from a logical standpoint!

Answer (score 2):

This would be simplified by adding a `selected` class when you click on element.

The current problem is that you will be adding new mouseout event handler each time a click occurs. A new one does not remove the old one

The following will check if the selected class exists before changing the image during the hover events

```
$("#targetBtn").on({
  "mouseover": function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src ', 'images/_hover.png');
    }

  },
  "mouseout": function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      $(this).find('img').attr('src ', 'images/_mouseout.png');
    }

  },
  "click": function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    var imgSrc = $(this).hasClass('selected') ? 'images/_selected.png' : 'images/_hover.png';
    $(this).find('img').attr('src ', imgSrc);

  }
});
```

Comment: This looks like a better solution. THANKS ALOT!